# Adding ppa's on Elementary OS freya doesn't work

Tags: software-installation, elementary-os, ppa

I wanted to install FinalTerm on my elementaryos freya installation, so I added the ppa with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:finalterm/daily`. However, when I tried running `sudo apt-get install finalterm` (after running update) it gives me:

```
kyr@kbx:~$ sudo apt-get install finalterm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package finalterm
```

Why does this appear?

Comment: What's in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`? There should be a new file called `finalterm-daily-precise.list`.

Comment: @garethTheRed It's `trusty`, but yeah, it's there.

Comment: Looking at the `ppa`, it only seems available up to `saucy`. No `trusty` build yet. A quick Google shows people building from source for now.